# RenderTargetBitmap is blurry

Tags: c#, wpf, image

Hi i'm creating an image in memory from a Canvas using a PngBitmapEncoder.

```
public void CaptureGraphic()
{
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
    canvas.SnapsToDevicePixels = true;
    canvas.Height = IMAGEHEIGHT;
    canvas.Width = IMAGEWIDTH;
    Draw(canvas);
    canvas.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, IMAGEWIDTH, IMAGEHEIGHT));
    member.MemberImage = GetPngFromUIElement(canvas);
}

public static System.Drawing.Image GetPngFromUIElement(Canvas source)
{
    int width = (int)source.ActualWidth;
    int height = (int)source.ActualHeight;

    if (width == 0)
        width = (int)source.Width;
    if (height == 0)
        height = (int)source.Height;


    RenderTargetBitmap bitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap(width, height, 96d, 96d, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
    bitmap.Render(source);

    PngBitmapEncoder enc = new PngBitmapEncoder();
    enc.Interlace = PngInterlaceOption.Off;
    enc.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmap));

    System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
    enc.Save(ms);

    System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);

    ms.Flush();
    ms.Dispose();

    return image;
}
```

Then i'm sending the image to the printer using the GDI+ DrawImage() method. However the printed result is blurry.

I've tried to match the original canvas size to the printed size to avoid any scaling, equally i've tried to make the original considerably bigger so the scaled image retains the quality however the final printed image is always blurred.

Can anyone offer any suggestions/alternatives. I have a considerable GDI+ print routine already setup and moving to wpf documents is not an option just yet.

Thanks

Comment: I think you could help your self by adding more tags to the question.

Answer (score 1):

You're capturing the bitmap at 96 DPI. Instead of using 96 in the constructor of the RenderTargetBitmap, try to match the DPI of your printer output. Alternatively, you could do the math and calculate the difference in width/height and rescale the image on the report accordingly (the result is the image on the report will appear smaller).

Comment: Thanks Jacob, yea i'm getting there. I had tried incresing the dpi in the constructor but that was cutting off the image, i had to increase the image size as well as the dpi and then scale down the image in the report as you say. Only problem is now that everything has slowed right down.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same blurry result and have come up with the following piece of code, which applies the same idea with the offset, but using the Offset property on the DrawingVisual (since I was using DrawDrawing, which doesn't have an overload with the offset argument):

```
public static Image ToBitmap(Image source)
{
    var dv = new DrawingVisual();
    // Blur workaround
    dv.Offset = new Vector(0.5, 0.5);
    using (var dc = dv.RenderOpen())
        dc.DrawDrawing(((DrawingImage)source.Source).Drawing);

    var bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)source.Width, (int)source.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
    bmp.Render(dv);

    var bitMapImage = new Image();
    bitMapImage.Source = bmp;
    bitMapImage.Width = source.Width;
    bitMapImage.Height = source.Height;

    return bitMapImage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. To avoid blurry text and lines, I had to draw everything with an offset of 0.5 in X and Y direction. E.g, an horizontal line could be

```
drawingContext.DrawLine(pen, new Point(10.5,10.5), new Point(100.5,10.5));
```

In my case, I was rendering to a RenderTargetBitmap in a different thread to improve the UI performance. The rendered bitmap is then frozen and drawn onto the UI using

```
drawingContext.DrawImage(bitmap, new Rect(0.5, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height));
```

Here, I needed an additional offset of 0.5, but (strangely) only in X direction, so that the rendered image did not look Blurry any more.